# Failed to resolve: customview-1.1.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencias

soy nuevo en android, a la hora de compilar me sale este error, es un poco raro, porque hasta hace no mucho no me salía, y no e hecho ningún cambio importante en el proyecto que recuerde, e intentado sincronizar gradle, pero me da error 404, e intentado buscar donde está esta dependencia, porque yo no e puesto ninguna, así que no tengo idea, estoy bastante confundido, pensé que iba a ser un problema fácil de resolver, pero no le encuentro solución, no puedo hacer nada con el error 404, estoy usando Avira VPN y Turbo VPN para conectarme, porque sin vpn es imposible en mi país, gracias a ellos puedo desarrollar en android, si alguien me podría decir si es que tengo que agregar algo a los archivos gradle o quitar algo se lo agradecería, estoy bastante estresado con ello, los errores de android studio me superan a veces

Esto es todo lo que me muestra cuando sincronizo

```
Failed to resolve: customview-1.1.0
Affected Modules: app
```

Esto me muestra cuando intento compilar:
nota: aquí está la URL que me da error:

> 1: Task failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
>   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>   Could not find customview-1.1.0.jar (androidx.customview:customview:1.1.0).
>   Searched in the following locations:
>   https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/customview/customview/1.1.0/customview-1.1.0.jar

gradle app

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.navigationrecicler"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner 
"androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
}

dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0'
def work_version = "2.6.0"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"
implementation "com.anggrayudi:storage:0.12.0"
implementation 'com.github.skydoves:progressview:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
implementation 'com.github.mmin18:realtimeblurview:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.5.1'
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:3.3.5'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.4.0'
}
```

gradle proyect

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options 
common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.10"
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"

}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Parece que importaste una librería y es ahí tu problema. ¿Qué hay en tu gradle?

Comment: hola @FranqoBalsamo ya incluí los archivos gradle en la respuesta